# Image Gallery on C#

Tags: c#, image, gallery

What I have to do is this:

Make an image gallery that has 5 buttons which each one select a folder of images.

Other two buttons for next and previous of the folder you are in. In my line 76, it says

> argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.collection.Generic.list' to string

Any ideas?

Here's an image of the console
http://postimg.org/image/nct5pwdit/

Line 76 says:

```
pictureBox1.Load(semestres[semac].imagen[]);
```

I have the same command like 6 times.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class semestres
{
    public List<string> imagen = new List<string>();
    private int _semestre;
    public int canti;
    public int actual;
    public int c;

    public semestres(int semestre, List<string> imagenes)
    {
        _semestre = semestre;
        imagen = imagenes;
        c = imagen.Count;
        actual = 0;
    }
    public int semestre
    {
        get
        {
            return _semestre;
        }
        set
        {
            c = imagen.Count;
        }
    }
    public int can
    {
        get
        {
            return c;
        }
        set
        {
            c = imagen.Count;
        }
    }
}

namespace Visor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int cont;
        private int semac;
        private int _cant;
        private int next;
        private List<semestres> semestres = new List<semestres>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cont = semestres[semac].actual;
            cont--;
            if (cont >= 0)
            {
                pictureBox1.Load(semestres[semac].imagen[]);
                semestres[semac].actual = cont;
            }
            else
            {
                //       MessageBox("Esta es la primer imagen");
                cont = 0;
                semestres[semac].actual = cont;
                pictureBox1.Load(semestres[semac].imagen);
            }
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cont = semestres[semac].actual;
            next = semestres[semac].c;
            cont++;
            if (cont < next)
            {
                pictureBox1.Load(semestres[semac].imagen);
                semestres[semac].actual = cont;
            }
            else
            {
                //       MessageBox("Esta es la ultima imagen");
                cont--;
                semestres[semac].actual = cont;
                pictureBox1.Load(semestres[semac].imagen(cont));
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            semac = 0;
            try
            {
                if (semestres[0].c > 0)
                {
                    cont = semestres[0].actual;
                    pictureBox1.Load(semestres[0].imagen(cont));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
                file.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
                file.Filter = "Images (*.BMP; *.JPG; *.GIF)|*.BMP; *.JPG; *.GIF|" + "All files(*.*)|*.*";
                file.FilterIndex = 1;
                file.Multiselect = true;
                file.RestoreDirectory = true;
                file.ShowDialog();
                string[] imgs = file.FileNames;
                List<string> imagenes = new List<string>();
                foreach (string imagen in imgs)
                {
                    imagenes.Add(imagen);
                }
                semestres.Add(new semestres(1, imagenes));
                pictureBox1.Load(imagenes[0]);
                semestres[0].actual = 0;
                cont = 0;
            }
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn_3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn_sal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you point out which line is line 76? Don't really feel like counting it out...

Comment: line 74      if (cont >= 0)
       75     {
       76         pictureBox1.Load(semestres[semac].imagen[]);
       77         semestres[semac].actual = cont;
       78     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have this:

```
pictureBox1.Load(semestres[semac].imagen);
```

Well the problem is that imagen is a `List<string>`. `Picturebox.Load(string)` takes a `string`, not a `List<string>`. So you need to get a string from that list instead of passing the whole list. One way would be:

```
pictureBox1.Load(semestres[semac].imagen[0]);
```

This would load the first image in that list.

Alternatively, you might be trying to do:

```
pictureBox1.Load(semestres[semac].imagen[cont]);
```

You just need to determine what the correct index is that you're trying to specify.

Comment: Thank you, that worked well, now i got logic errors. Have a good day.